# Functions name from string

Tags: javascript

How can someone get all functions name from a string in JavaScript?

Let say my string is:

```
var test = "function hello(){} function world(count){ alert('Count:'+count)}"
```

how can i get the functions names ( the content of the string is random ) :

```
hello
world
```

can someone please show me how that can be done in pure javascript?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Your string contains JavaScript code with a syntax error. Is that intentional? Supporting a string containing syntax errors vs. only supporting a string containing syntactically-correct code could affect the approach you take to solving the problem. Separately: What about *other* forms of creating functions (function expressions, etc.)? Do you need to support them? What about generator functions?

Comment: Yes that to show that sometimes the string have syntax errors :9

Comment: The nature of a syntax error is that it means code **cannot** be correctly parsed from the point at which the error occurs through the end of the code.

Comment: I understand you, but to just understand the basics now i only wanted the name of each functions if all syntax is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parsing JavaScript with custom code is no simple task. Think for instance of code that includes `alert("this is not a function haha() {}")`.

But if you are content with a simple, imperfect approach, then you could use a regular expression, like this:

```js
function getFunctionNames(src) {
    var re = /\bfunction\s*\*?\s*\b(\w+)\s*\(/g,
        match,
        names = [];
    while(match = re.exec(test)) names.push(match[1]);
    return names;
}

var test = "function hello(){} function* world(count){ alert('Count:'+count}";
console.log(getFunctionNames(test));
```

Comment: I get what you mean... true. I'm just trying to see how to do that, but how can this function be able to also support  generator functions?

Comment: Updated to also recognise generator functions. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes that was the answer to all my questions. Thank you very Much!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use it to prevent injections, I've a bad news for you.

In any way, you can find function names using regex

```js
var test = "function hello(){} function world(count){ alert('Count:'+count}"
var res = test.match(/(?<=(function\s))(\w+)/g)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: @trincot where do you see the syntax error? Answers sometimes aren't perfect and can be improved, if you think you can raise the quality of answer then you can edit it or you can just suggest some change

Comment: Apologies! I was too harsh! It is true that it works in JS engines that already support the [ES2018 lookbehind assertions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind). At the moment of writing Firefox, Edge and Safari don't support it yet. They notify a syntax error in the regular expression literal.